# localhost header redirects to localhost/link

Tags: php, http, header, location, localhost

I have designed a home page on my pc which can be accesses through localhost/Home. Here i enter a site name and it must take me to that site.
I have used 
    header("Location: url ");
function in my code and it takes in the site name properly. But the problem is, any site i try to open, it takes me to "localhost/site" like if i enter www.google.com in the input, it takes me to localhost/www.google.com

Is there any way where i can exit local host and go to google.com on input? or is it not possible?

Comment: You're using a bad value in your redirect. Show us your code so we can point it out to you.

Comment: In the php, check to see if 'http' or 'https' exists at the beginning of the url, if not add it.

Comment: try `header("Location: http://www.google.com");`

Answer (score 1):

You would need to give the complete absolute URL, including the scheme. Example:

```
header('Location: http://www.google.com');
```

Otherwise, the client would treat the URL as relative one.